# Regex php, remove tag table with class

Tags: php, regex

I have content:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tbl-photo right">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <amp-img layout="responsive" height="500" width="760" alt="" src="https://example.com/uploads/images/0 Богдан-Цырдя(1).jpg" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-responsive i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-layout">
                    <i-amphtml-sizer style="padding-top: 65.7895%;"></i-amphtml-sizer>
                    <img decoding="async" alt="" src="https://example.com/uploads/images/0 Богдан-Цырдя(1).jpg" class="i-amphtml-fill-content i-amphtml-replaced-content">
                </amp-img>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date"> Foto: example.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need remove this table with `preg_replace`.

I need remove only this table with class `tbl-photo right`. How I can do this?

My expression:

```
$pattern = '~<table(?>(?!</?table).)*</table>~is';
$output = preg_replace($pattern, '', $body);
```

But this remove all tables...

Comment: Since the table is the whole content, you can just return an empty string.

Comment: If the above is not working try with this one:  /(?:\<table)(?:.*)(?:tbl\-photo\ right)(?:.*)(?:\/table\>)/

Comment: This one should help /(?:\<table)(?:[^table\>]*)(?:tbl\-photo\ right)(?:[^table\>]*)(?:\/table\>)/

Comment: "_I need remove this table with preg_replace._" Why `preg_replace`? Homework? Why not use [DOMDocument](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)?

Comment: I'm with kerbholz; don't use regex on valid html, use DomDocument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use http://buildregex.com/. It's such an awesome and simple page to build regex! You gonna find it useful for sure.

If you're not that much into regex, one of those should do the job:

`/(?:\<table)(?:.*)(?:tbl\-photo\ right)(?:.*)(?:\/table\>)/`

`/(?:\<table)(?:[^table\>]*)(?:tbl\-photo\ right)(?:[^table\>]*)(?:\/table\>)/`

Comment: not one is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try the regex `<table(?=[\s\S]*(class="tbl-photo right"))[\s\S]*?<\/table>`

This will match everything between table tags with class name `tbl-photo right`

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/kJ4voB/1/)